# Copy file exception with TrueZIP

Tags: java, truezip

Here is my code to copy a `war` file to another using **TrueZIP**.

```
TFile srcFile = new TFile(sourceFilePath);
TFile destFile = new TFile(destFilePath);
if (!destFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
    destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
}

try {
    srcFile.cp_rp(destFile);
    TVFS.umount();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For example, source file location:

> `I:\Code-Base\test.7.2.0\projects\test\main\branches\test.7.2.0_for_test\ui\portlets\dist\portlets.war\WEB-INF\server-config.wsdd`

and destination location:

> `D:\deploy\work\237798_237980\web\deploy\prtlets.war\WEB-INF\server-config.wsdd`

I've already checked that both paths exists, but I get an `InputException` error::

```
de.schlichtherle.truezip.io.InputException: de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsReadOnlyArchiveFileSystemException: This is a read-only archive file system!
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.socket.IOSocket.copy(IOSocket.java:102)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TBIO.cp0(TBIO.java:221)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TBIO.cp_r0(TBIO.java:179)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TBIO.cp_r(TBIO.java:138)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TFile.cp_rp(TFile.java:3210)
    at com.accela.work.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:110)
    at com.accela.work.Worker.getUpgradePackageByVersion(Worker.java:162)
    at com.accela.work.Main.generateUpgradePackage(Main.java:114)
    at com.accela.work.Main.getUpgradePackageByVersion(Main.java:107)
    at com.accela.work.Main.main(Main.java:75)
Caused by: de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsReadOnlyArchiveFileSystemException: This is a read-only archive file system!
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsReadOnlyArchiveFileSystem.mknod(FsReadOnlyArchiveFileSystem.java:54)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsBasicArchiveController$1Output.mknod(FsBasicArchiveController.java:273)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsBasicArchiveController$1Output.getLocalTarget(FsBasicArchiveController.java:220)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsBasicArchiveController$1Output.getLocalTarget(FsBasicArchiveController.java:217)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsContextController$Output.getLocalTarget(FsContextController.java:296)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsContextController$Output.getLocalTarget(FsContextController.java:280)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.socket.DelegatingOutputSocket.getLocalTarget(DelegatingOutputSocket.java:47)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.socket.DelegatingOutputSocket.getLocalTarget(DelegatingOutputSocket.java:21)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.socket.DelegatingOutputSocket.getLocalTarget(DelegatingOutputSocket.java:47)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.socket.DelegatingOutputSocket.getLocalTarget(DelegatingOutputSocket.java:21)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsSyncController$Output.getLocalTarget(FsSyncController.java:421)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsSyncController$Output.getLocalTarget(FsSyncController.java:408)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController$Output$1GetLocalTarget.call(FsLockController.java:498)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController$Output$1GetLocalTarget.call(FsLockController.java:495)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController.locked(FsLockController.java:316)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController.writeLocked(FsLockController.java:268)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController$Output.getLocalTarget(FsLockController.java:501)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController$Output.getLocalTarget(FsLockController.java:484)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.socket.DelegatingOutputSocket.getLocalTarget(DelegatingOutputSocket.java:47)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.socket.DelegatingOutputSocket.getLocalTarget(DelegatingOutputSocket.java:21)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFalsePositiveArchiveController$1Output$GetLocalTarget.call(FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.java:374)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFalsePositiveArchiveController$1Output$GetLocalTarget.call(FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.java:367)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFalsePositiveArchiveController$TryChild.call(FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.java:507)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.call(FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.java:104)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFalsePositiveArchiveController$1Output.getLocalTarget(FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.java:364)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFalsePositiveArchiveController$1Output.getLocalTarget(FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.java:348)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.socket.InputSocket.getPeerTarget(InputSocket.java:50)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsBasicArchiveController$1Input.getDelegate(FsBasicArchiveController.java:199)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.socket.DelegatingInputSocket.getBoundSocket(DelegatingInputSocket.java:43)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.socket.DelegatingInputSocket.newInputStream(DelegatingInputSocket.java:63)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsContextController$Input.newInputStream(FsContextController.java:273)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsResourceController$Input.newInputStream(FsResourceController.java:242)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.socket.DelegatingInputSocket.newInputStream(DelegatingInputSocket.java:63)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsSyncController$Input.newInputStream(FsSyncController.java:378)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController$Input$1NewInputStream.call(FsLockController.java:455)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController$Input$1NewInputStream.call(FsLockController.java:452)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController.locked(FsLockController.java:328)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController.writeLocked(FsLockController.java:268)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController$Input.newInputStream(FsLockController.java:459)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFinalizeController$Input.newInputStream(FsFinalizeController.java:177)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFalsePositiveArchiveController$1Input$NewInputStream.call(FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.java:333)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFalsePositiveArchiveController$1Input$NewInputStream.call(FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.java:326)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFalsePositiveArchiveController$TryChild.call(FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.java:507)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.call(FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.java:104)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFalsePositiveArchiveController$1Input.newInputStream(FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.java:323)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.socket.IOSocket.copy(IOSocket.java:100)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TrueZIP does a simple test to check if the archive file is writable. If this test fails, the archive file system is set read-only as indicated by the exception.

In most cases, this is simply an issue with the access permissions. But Windows is particularly bitchy. For example, if there is another tool concurrently accessing the archive file (many Explorer plug-ins do this) then the file is effectively read-only, too.

So please stay away from the archive file (and best, its directory) while the operation is running.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer and Truezip is really great API library for accessing archive file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do a replace on a read-only file, because you would have to delete it, i.e. write to it.

Make sure your destFile is writeable.